# moveit! trajectory execution aborted

Tags: control, robotic-arm, ros, motion-planning

I'm trying to send a custom arm to a pose through moveit_commander_cmdline.py, it fails after sending to the said pose using " go default_pose" and returns an error.

```
ABORTED: Solution found but controller failed during execution Failed while moving to default_pose
```

What could be responsible for this error? And How can I fix it?

The info and warning from my launch file is:

```
Combined planning and execution request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning and execution pipeline.  [ INFO]
[1564316145.917054276, 2449.038000000]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1  [ INFO]
[1564316145.917319501, 2449.038000000]: Starting state is just outside bounds (joint 'hand_2_joint'). Assuming within bounds.  [INFO]
[1564316145.920258662, 2449.038000000]: Planner configuration 'pickup' will use planner 'geometric::RRT'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.  [ INFO]
[1564316145.925439206, 2449.038000000]: RRT: Starting planning with 1 states already in datastructure  [ INFO]
[1564316145.967999895, 2449.047000000]: RRT: Created 32 states  [ INFO]
[1564316145.970035099, 2449.047000000]: Solution found in 0.047451 seconds  [ INFO]
[1564316146.019862352, 2449.049000000]: SimpleSetup: Path simplification took 0.049343 seconds and changed from 4 to 2 states  [ INFO]
[1564316146.022653470, 2449.049000000]: Planning adapters have added states at index positions: [ 0 ]  [ WARN]
[1564316148.097078345, 2449.242000000]: Controller /custom_controller failed with error code PATH_TOLERANCE_VIOLATED  [ WARN]
[1564316148.097649266, 2449.242000000]: Controller handle /custom_controller reports status ABORTED  [ INFO]
[1564316148.097916866, 2449.242000000]: Completed trajectory execution with status ABORTED ...
```

My controller.yaml in moveit! configuration folder is:

```
controller_list:
  - name: /custom_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - hand_2_joint
```

And my controller.yaml in my robot package folder is:

```
hand_controller:
  type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  joints:
    - hand_2_joint
  constraints:
    goal_time: 0.6                  
    stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
    hand_2_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}                   
  stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
  state_publish_rate:  50            
  action_monitor_rate: 10

gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains:
  hand_2_joint: {p: 0.0, i: 0.0, d: 0.0}
```

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* imraj, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. You have provided lots of useful information here, but not actually asked a question. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information, and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I suspect that you want to understand why the move failed, and how to fix it, but it would be good to know for sure. I suspect it may have something to do with the "Starting state is just outside bounds" message.

Comment: On stack exchange, it is better to edit your question to add information requested in comments, rather than adding more comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. If all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied up (deleted).